# Upgraded Drupal - now there is serialized data in the database

Tags: php, serialization, drupal-6

I just upgraded to Drupal 6.25 as well as upgrading some modules to the latest versions: profile_checkboxes, views, devel and date. Now when I go into a view that was previously setup to display site registrants, I see several values, First Name (stored in the profile_values table) for example, being returned in the view as a serialized array - like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:11:"First Name";}
```

If I go into the profile editor on the front-end, it's being returned as as array there as well. If I update the First Name from the front-end and submit, it updates in the database without the array.

Can anybody give me any help as to why this may have happened and what I can do to fix it? Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

**Restore the backup you made before upgrading.**

Failing that, just replace the Drupal files with that of the previous version to get a working state back.

Debug from there.

Comment: The database is changing on a daily basis, so I hate to backup to a pre-upgrade version and lose all the new additions to the site. However, if I roll old code back into the site without rolling back the DB, won't that give me errors?

Comment: I did some additional research, and is seems that specifically the First Name in the profile_values table (f_id = 1) was serialized with the upgrade. I checked one of my other databases that I did not do the upgrade on and First Name is NOT serialized in there. Any idea where I would look to 1) figure out WHY Drupal did this, and 2) fix it so that when somebody views their profile they don't get serialized output on their first name?

Comment: 2 quick fix options... 1) Write a script to load the infected value from the DB, unserialize() them then update the DB en masse. 2) Where this value is displayed in Drupal, just wrap it with an unserialize().